# IOS Provisioning Portal - Device is not unique

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning

I am working on a project for which i bought a couple of iPad minis.  I added both of the iPads to the provisioning portal as devices.  I then try to modify my provisioning profile and click on both of the devices to add them to the certificate.  When i hit save/submit to add the devices to the certificate i receive the following error,  "The selected device(s) are not unique. Please select unique device(s)."

Both of the devices have different names in the portal and different UDID.  I fear that The issue could be related to adding the devices through Xcode 4.5, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem on my end.  When I was adding the devices through Xcode, one of the devices was somehow added twice in some odd glitch but with two different names.  Deleting the extra device which I guess did have a duplicate udid took care of the issue.  This was also preventing other devices although those devices did not have duplicate udid in the system.  Hope this helps anyone that might encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue before. The workaround is to just create a new provisioning profile.

Comment: Just tried that work around and it did not work for me, still coming up with the same error.

Comment: Anyway, it's some erratic thing. Try deleting one iPad and then adding it again after generating the provisioning file.

Answer (score 0):

might be the udid: (for IOS7, requires new method to get udid).

[Issue with developer portal added device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378093/issue-with-developer-portal-added-device/19594548#19594548)