# Issue with developer portal added device

Tags: iphone, xcode, udid, iphone-developer-program

I am facing an issue related to apple developer portal. I had added a new UDID (with all alphabets as capitals )to the dev account. But somehow now the device shows UDID with all lowercase letters. This may be the reason i am unable to deploy an adhoc build to this device.
    If i disable this device and try to add again with a different name and same UDID(pasted as Capitalized alphabets), the device previously disabled becomes active again and the new device is not added.

I am not sure if this question fits around here in stackoverflow, in which case it will be closed very soon :-). But if it does, it would be very helpful if someone could let me know a workaround through this issue.

Comment: Could someone help out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's the problem:

In iOS7 UDIDs are no longer available via the "send me my UDID apps.

UDIDs are ONLY available via Xcode or connecting to itunes.

The ones sent by the apps are incorrect and will fail - they all have FFFFF as the start...

To find the correct UDID, connect to itunes.

click on:

My Device->serial number (it will switch to the UDID)

grrrrr..............

Very nice woman at Apple walked me through it.

S

Comment: Thanks for such an important info. I have informed my colleagues and managers of this too. Cheers :-)